# I can't use my react-native application in ZEBRA TC520K device

Tags: reactjs, react-native, zebra-scanners

I'm employee that try to make react-native application for my work. It's finished but I have issue that I can't use it properly in ZEBRA TC520K device excepts other devices. Here's my code.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { View, Text, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, TextInput, Button} from "react-native";
import { Col, Row, Grid } from 'react-native-easy-grid';
import axios from 'axios';

const Home = () => {
    const [textPartNo, setTextPartNo] = useState('');
    const [textPartSerial, setTextPartSerial] = useState('');

    const [dataRes, setdataRes] = useState(null);
    const [dataJSON, setdataJSON] = useState(null);
    const [dataShow, setdataShow] = useState(null);

    const [partNo,setPartNo] = useState();
    const [partSeri,setPartSeri] = useState();
    const [zno,setZno] = useState();
    const [goh,setGoh] = useState();
    const [mC,setMC] = useState();
    const [kishName,setKishName] = useState();
    const [kibaName,setKibaName] = useState();
    const [lot,setLot] = useState();
    const [sLot,setSLot] = useState();
    const [kouTei,setKouTei] = useState();
    const [tonYuSu,setTonYuSu] = useState();
    const [placeName,setPlaceName] = useState();
    const [boxName,setBoxName] = useState();
    const [partVol,setPartVol] = useState();
    const [c_Type,setC_Type] = useState();

    const textPartNoRef = useRef(null);
    const textPartSerialRef = useRef(null);

    const handleFindButtonPress = () => {
        if (textPartNo && textPartSerial) {
        const apiUrl = 'http://...myip.../AM/PICS/PartFindInfo/Api/GetPartState';
        const options = {
            params: {
            part_no: textPartNo,
            part_seri: textPartSerial,
            },
        };

        axios
            .get(apiUrl, options)
            .then((response) => {
                setdataRes(response.data);
                setdataShow(null);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
            });
        }
    };

    const fetchData = () => {
        if (textPartNo && textPartSerial) {
            const apiUrl = 'http://...myip.../AM/PICS/PartFindInfo/Api/GetPartState';
            const options = {
                params: {
                    part_no: textPartNo,
                    part_seri: textPartSerial,
                },
            };

            axios
                .get(apiUrl, options)
                .then((response) => {
                    setdataRes(response.data);
                    setdataShow(null);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
                });
        }
    };

    const handleClearButtonPress = () => {
        setTextPartNo('');
        setTextPartSerial('');
        setPartNo('');
        setPartSeri('');
        setZno('');
        setGoh('');
        setMC('');
        setKishName('');
        setKibaName('');
        setLot('');
        setSLot('');
        setKouTei('');
        setTonYuSu('');
        setPlaceName('');
        setBoxName('');
        setPartVol('');
        setC_Type('');
        setdataShow(null);
        setdataRes(null);

        textPartNoRef.current.focus();
      };

      const handlePartNoChange = (text) => {
        setTextPartNo(text);
            if (text.length === 9) {
                textPartSerialRef.current.focus(); // Move cursor to the second input
            }
        };
    

    // useEffect(() => {

    //     const apiUrl = 'http://...myip.../AM/PICS/PartFindInfo/Api/GetPartState';

    //     const options = {
    //         params: {
    //             part_no: '100100611',
    //             part_seri: 'IA3829UE4N1R'
    //         }
    //     };

    //     const apiUrl = 'http://...myip.../AM/PICS/PartFindInfo/Api/GetPartState';

    //     const options = {
    //         params: {
    //           part_no: '',
    //           part_seri: '',
    //           }
    //     }

    //     if (textPartNo && textPartSerial) {
    //         //const apiUrl = 'http://...myip.../AM/PICS/PartFindInfo/Api/GetPartState';
    //         const options = {
    //           params: {
    //             part_no: textPartNo,
    //             part_seri: textPartSerial,
    //             }
    //         }
    //     }

    //     axios.get(apiUrl, options)
    //         .then(response => {
    //             setdataRes(response.data);
    //             //console.log(response.data);
    //         })
    //         .catch(error => {
    //             console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
    //         });
            
    // }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        if ( dataRes !== null ) {
            setdataJSON(JSON.parse(dataRes))
        }
    }, [dataRes]);

    useEffect(() => {
            //console.log(data2);
        if( dataJSON !== null ) {   
            //console.log("testloop");
            //console.log(data2.length);
            if( dataJSON.length > 0 ) {
                setdataShow(dataJSON[0]);
                //console.log("testloop2");
            }
        }   
    }, [dataJSON]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if ( dataShow !== null ) {
            setPartNo(dataShow.PartNo);
            setPartSeri(dataShow.PartSeri);
            setZno(dataShow.Zno)
            setGoh(dataShow.Goh);
            setMC(dataShow.McName);
            setKishName(dataShow.KISHNAME);
            setKibaName(dataShow.KIBANAME);
            setLot(dataShow.LOT);
            setSLot(dataShow.SLOT);
            setKouTei(dataShow.KOUTEI);
            setTonYuSu(dataShow.TONYUSU);
            setPlaceName(dataShow.PlaceName);
            setBoxName(dataShow.BoxName);
            setPartVol(dataShow.PartVol);
            setC_Type(dataShow.C_TYPE);
            
        }
    }, [dataShow]);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
    }, [textPartNo, textPartSerial]);

    //console.log(data1);
    //console.log(data2);
    //console.log(dataShow);
    //console.log(pn);
    //console.log(ps);
    
    
    return (
        <SafeAreaView>
            {/* <Text style={styles.text}>Test query: P/N: {partNo} P/Serial: {partSeri} </Text> */}
            <Text style={styles.header1}>PartFindInfo - PDA [Search]</Text>
            <Text style={styles.text}>Input Part No. or Part Serial No.</Text>
            <TextInput
                ref={textPartNoRef}
                style={styles.input}
                onChangeText={handlePartNoChange}
                value={textPartNo}
                placeholder="P/N"
                returnKeyType="next"
            />
            <TextInput
                ref={textPartSerialRef}
                style={styles.input}
                onChangeText={text => setTextPartSerial(text)}
                value={textPartSerial}
                placeholder="P/Serial"
                returnKeyType="done"
            />
            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', marginLeft: 12, marginRight: 12 }}>
                <Button
                    color={'green'}
                    //style={styles.button}
                    title="Find"
                    onPress={handleFindButtonPress}
                />
                <Button
                    color={'gray'}
                    //style={styles.button}
                    title="Clear"
                    onPress={handleClearButtonPress}
                />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.header2}>Zno: {zno}</Text>
                <Grid>
                    <Col size={15}>
                        <Row style={styles.cell}>
                            <Text>M/C:</Text>
                        </Row>
                        <Row style={styles.cell}>
                            <Text>KISH:</Text>
                        </Row>
                        <Row style={styles.cell}>
                            <Text>KIBA:</Text>
                        </Row>
                        <Row style={styles.cell}>
                            <Text>LOT:</Text>
                        </Row>
                        <Row style={styles.cell}>
                            <Text>SLOT:</Text>
                        </Row>
                        <Row style={styles.cell}>
                            <Text>MEN:</Text>
                        </Row>
                        <Row style={styles.cell}>
                            <Text>QTY:</Text>
                        </Row>
                        <Row style={styles.cell}>
                            <Text>Place:</Text>
                        </Row>
                        <Row style={styles.cell}>
                            <Text>Box:</Text>
                        </Row>
                        <Row style={styles.cell}>
                            <Text>PartVol:</Text>
                        </Row>
                        <Row style={styles.cell}>
                            <Text>C_TYPE:</Text>
                        </Row>
                    </Col>
                    <Col size={60}>
                        <Row style={styles.cell}>
                            <Text style={styles.textbold}>{mC}-{goh}</Text>
                        </Row>
                        <Row style={styles.cell}>
                            <Text>{kishName}</Text>
                        </Row>
                        <Row style={styles.cell}>
                            <Text>{kibaName}</Text>
                        </Row>
                        <Row style={styles.cell}>
                            <Text>{lot}</Text>
                        </Row>
                        <Row style={styles.cell}>
                            <Text>{sLot}</Text>
                        </Row>
                        <Row style={styles.cell}>
                            <Text>{kouTei}</Text>
                        </Row>
                        <Row style={styles.cell}>
                            <Text>{tonYuSu}</Text>
                        </Row>
                        <Row style={styles.cell}>
                            <Text>{placeName}</Text>
                        </Row>
                        <Row style={styles.cell}>
                            <Text>{boxName}</Text>
                        </Row>
                        <Row style={styles.cell}>
                            <Text>{partVol}</Text>
                        </Row>
                        <Row style={styles.cell}>
                            <Text>{c_Type}</Text>
                        </Row>
                    </Col>
                </Grid>
            </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    input: {
        height: 40,
        margin: 12,
        borderWidth: 1,
        padding: 10
    },
    text: {
        margin: 12
    },
    textbold: {
        fontWeight: 'bold'
    },
    header1: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontSize: 25,
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: 'black'
    },
    header2: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontSize: 20,
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: 'blue'
    },
    container: {
        width: '100%',
        height: 250,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        borderWidth: 1,
        marginTop: 12,
        padding: 10
    },
    cell: {
        justifyContent: 'left',
        alignItems: 'center'
    }
})

export default Home;
```

So it's find part info application in my company and here's my picture that show what I have an issue.

[My application when run between normal telephone device and ZEBRA TC520K device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfqTk.jpg)

By the way, This application using API URL (I change real IP to ...myip... for the company's confidential) to connect data to show at below buttons or at the grid.

If you see in the picture there's two devices and ZEBRA TC520K device can't show data like other devices. How can I make ZEBRA TC520K device can show data.

Answer (score 0):

Will the zebra device show the text when you amend the handleClearButtonPress function like this.

```js
    const handleClearButtonPress = () => {
        setTextPartNo('test of text');
        setTextPartSerial('test of text');
        setPartNo('test of text');
        setPartSeri('test of text');
        setZno('test of text');
        setGoh('test of text');
        setMC('test of text');
        setKishName('test of text');
        setKibaName('test of text');
        setLot('test of text');
        setSLot('test of text');
        setKouTei('test of text');
        setTonYuSu('test of text');
        setPlaceName('test of text');
        setBoxName('test of text');
        setPartVol('test of text');
        setC_Type('test of text');
        setdataShow(null);
        setdataRes(null);

        textPartNoRef.current.focus();
      };
```

It might be that the text were not shown due to different screen ratio

Comment: When I use your function and press the button. It's shows normally. So it's not about different screen ratio. Are there codes that I need to add or some extensions to make API can use in the app when install in the Zebra device?

Answer (score -1):

Using React Native in conjunction with Zebra can present some challenges. I'm not entirely sure of your specific requirements, but I'd like to provide you with some potentially useful resources. Here are a couple of links for your reference:

Zebra's GitHub repositories
https://github.com/orgs/ZebraDevs/repositories?q=link-os&type=all&language=&sort=

Zebra's official technical documentation
https://techdocs.zebra.com/link-os/2-14/

I hope you find these resources helpful. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for sharing so I'll tell my requirements. I want to make the app that using Part No. and Part Serial to search data like how many Part Volumn of that part. My app just show data like sql query and display but with API instead. The issue I found is when I use the app in Zebra device. It's not show any data when I put Part No. and Part Serial in text boxes in the code but when I use in other devices like my phone It shows data like the picture that I compared. I don't know that Zebra need extensions or services to use API in the app so I want solutions that the app can use API maybe